# Generate matrix of unique pairs from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array

```
A = np.arange(1,11)
```

and I want to generate an array B such that

```
B = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]],[[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[6,9],[8,10]]]....)
```

for example, where B is an array with n=len(A)-1 entries, and B<sub>n</sub> consists of m=len(A)/2 pairs. No 2 columns B<sub>n1</sub> and B<sub>n2</sub> can have any pairs in common, they must always be unique across columns.

(I'm trying to create a league schedule for matches between players if that makes my question clearer)

Smaller example:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3,4])

B = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],
     [[1,3],[2,4]],
     [[1,4],[2,3]]])
```

Comment: Can you please give a smaller **but complete** example for clarity?

Comment: Done @mozway and fixed the length typo (n=len(A)-1,m=len(A)/2)

Answer (score 2):

I think you trying implement round-robin pairings generator.

I have found ready-to-go solution [here](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/65200-round-robin-pairings-generator/)

Unfortunately I was not able to run this code so I modified it, code provided:

```
def roundRobin(units, sets=None):
""" Generates a schedule of "fair" pairings from a list of units """
    units = list(units)
    if len(units) % 2:
        units.append(None)
    count = len(units)
    sets = sets or (count - 1)
    half = int(count / 2)
    schedule = []
    for turn in range(sets):
        pairings = []
        for i in range(half):
            pairings.append((units[i], units[count - i - 1]))
        units.insert(1, units.pop())
        schedule.append(pairings)
    return schedule

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for pairings in roundRobin(range(1, 11)):
        print(pairings)
```

UPD 15.03.2024 16:59 GMT+5

I have found better one, [Link here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament_schedule#Python)
Easer to follow and to edit, gl

Comment: Thanks, didn't know what the name for it was! Will try implementing and let you know

Comment: @Jack you can google it and find more suitable for your case, there is a lot of project on this problem